# root namespace coding convention in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, coding-style

Would you recommand prefixing global namespaces with `::`? (for instance `::std::cout` instead of `std::cout`) Why? Is it faster to parse for the C++ compiler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Only do this to disambiguate.

I have a piece of code where this is necessary since I’m in a namespace `X` which has a function for a standard deviation – `std`. Whenever I want to access the `std` namespace, I need to use `::std` because otherwise the compiler will think that I am referring to said function.

Concrete example:

```
namespace X {
    double std(::std::vector<double> const& values) { … }

    void foo(::std::vector<double> const& values) {
        ::std::cout << std(values) << ::std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: would not it be simpler to rename the function, really :P ?

Comment: @MatthieuM That’s the wrong solution. Naming functions is hard enough as it is. The function’s name is *correct* (“std” is the most widespread abbreviation for “standard deviation”) and should *not* be changed just to avoid name clashes.

Comment: +1 for an example where you actually **have** a reason to use the name std inside another namespace.

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with parsing speed. C++ uses [Argument-dependent name lookup - Koenig Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) and when you have to make sure that the compiler uses the symbol from the global root namespace you prefix it with `::`. If you don't the compiler might also use function definitions from other namespaces when it sees fit (depending on the lookup method).

So, it is better not to do it unless you have to.

Comment: ADL refers to the fact that when looking up an *unqualified* function call, the namespaces of the arguments will be added to the set of candidates, and it has nothing to do with any qualified identifier, which is what the question is about: qualified calls vs. fully qualified (including root namespace) calls.

Comment: ADL applies to the name lookup of all non-qualified function calls.  @trenki is right that using :: significantly changes name lookup.  Often to what is not wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to, as the compiler will

a) find it anyway
b) output an error if there are any ambiguations, like

```
namespace foo
{
  int test()
  {
    return 42;
  }
}

namespace bar
{
  namespace foo
  {
    int test()
    {
      return 42;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  using namespace bar;
  return foo::test(); // error, could be ::foo::test or ::bar::foo::test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any good reason to do this. It makes the code less readable, and should only be used when you explicitly must tell the compiler to use the root namespace. Like when there is ambiguities.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do that. It clutters your code and disables the option to implement a self-made variant of the functions you are using.

Comment: The question was if one would recommend it and I don't because of the reasons I listed in my second sentence ;)

Comment: In that case you are mistaken: it doesn’t. Using an explicit namespace (whether prefixed by the global namespace qualifier `::` or not) will *always* make it impossible to use a self-made variant of the function (unless you’re specialising `std::swap`). It is completely irrelevant whether the namespace is prefixed by `::`.