# Rules and Practices for Global Namespace Prefix?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

I've seen a lot of libraries referring to the global namespace (prepended `::`) in order to prevent confusions. In some codebase it seems pretty enforced as a coding rule, although the confusion rarely happens:

```cpp
namespace library_code {

namespace win32_backend {

void some_backend_internal_function() {
    ::SomeWin32GlobalFunction(...); // pretty much non-issue, different rules on naming
}

}

}
```

And sometimes even non-library codes are written as such:

```cpp
int main() {
    using namespace ::boost::math::constants;

    std::cout << "pi = " << pi<double>();

    return 0;
}
```

However, I've almost never seen that `std` namespace being prepended with global namespace prefix like `::std::max(a, b)`, even for such projects with strict rules. This gives me a confusion as in first glance it seems inconsistent.

Why do some projects use such mixed rules on using global namespaces? Is it just `std` being a popular exception? What are the justifications and insights?

Answer (score 0):

Well , this question may not have only one particular answer and many may disagree with my answer.

> I've seen a lot of libraries referring to the global namespace (prepended ::) in order to prevent confusions

Well namespace was designed to remove confusion when you have same identifiers at many places.It is standard to use it writing any c++ code.You can see boost library implementation as they have used namespace  correctly . It will give you idea how to implement in your code.

> However, I've almost never seen that std namespace being prepended like ::std::max(a, b), even for such projects with strict rules. This gives me a confusion as in first glance it seems inconsistent.

Well I never use `using namespace std` in my code and I strongly recommend others not to use it either. I have seen many professionals using `using namespace std` in their code.This is highly undesirable.Its like a habit for them to use it.Yes , and this is only in case of std because in code , if you don't use `using namespace std` 
, you have to use `std::`again and again , which is undesirable for many programmers.

If you use max() , you will not know in which namespace does it belong to , but when you use std::max() , well now you know its a part of standard library.

If you use `using namespace` for something apart from `std` , you may have some trouble afterwards and maintaining the code will take more effort which is undesirable.

Eg:
You have included many files , and you have max() defined in two name space `std` and `myNamespace` , now you have used

```
using namespace std;
using namespace myNamespace;
```

Now when you use `max()` , confusion will arise as max belongs to which namespace.

Comment: Well I should have been more careful with wording, sorry. What I was asking is not about why `std` namespace being explicit; it's about global namespace prefix (`::`) before `std` being omitted in almost all projects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404834/root-namespace-coding-convention-in-c

Comment: personally i never used global namespace prefix (::)

Comment: But those answers does not explain inconsistencies. All of those reasons (e.g., hard to read, unnecessary clutter, use only for disambiguation) could also be easily applied to non-`std` codes as well.

Comment: Only do this to disambiguate.

I have a piece of code where this is necessary since I’m in a namespace `X` which has a function for a standard deviation – `std`. Whenever I want to access the `std` namespace, I need to use `::std` because otherwise the compiler will think that I am referring to said function.

Concrete example:

    namespace X {
        double std(::std::vector<double> const& values) { … }
    
        void foo(::std::vector<double> const& values) {
            ::std::cout << std(values) << ::std::endl;
        }
    }

Comment: You're referring to [Konrad Rudolph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5404933/3567518). I also think it's one of the common practices. But what I'm seeing in large portion of C++ codes is that they commonly uses prepended `::` for non-`std` names despite there are no ambiguity at all, while never using it on `std` unless absolutely needed for disambiguation as quoted. Those particular inconsistencies are something that itches me to ask this question.